# Generating random number printed in random intervals with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, random

I am trying to generate random numbers using Math.random() that are logged / or written *in random intervals*...

I wrote the following:

```
function ranNum () {
  setInterval( function () {
  var myNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
  document.write(myNum+' ');
  return myNum;
  }, ranNum)
}

ranNum();
```

but the intervals are not random, in fact they seem to be null or zero, as there are endless numbers printed... I guess it's not possible to call a new instance of the ranNum function so the second parameter of setInterval is either 0 or always the same..

I was told recursion would be the solution here but fail to implement it.

Comment: use `setTimeout` instead `setInterval`

Comment: can't I randomize the interval period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As monkeyinsight points it, use `setTimeout`:

```
function ranNum () {
  setTimeout( function () {
  var myNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
  document.write(myNum+' ');
  ranNum(); //This makes the function call `recursive` (in a broad sense)
  return myNum;
  }, Math.round(Math.random()*10000) // The function in the setTimeout will be called in 0-10000ms
  );
}

ranNum();
```

Comment: I am choosing your answer because it was closer to my code / recursion, if even the other one seems more solid..

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random interval, use repeated `setTimeout`. `setInterval` just repeats on the same interval.

```
function ranNum () {
  schedule();
  function schedule() {
    setTimeout(go, Math.random() * 10000);
  }
  function go() {
    var myNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
    document.write(myNum+' ');
    schedule();
    // No return, it doesn't make any sense to return something from a timer function
  }
}
```

---

Side note: You don't want `document.write` for this. Your document will be *replaced* by the `document.write` after the first timer function calls. Instead, use modern DOM techniques like `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML`.

```js
var counter = 20;
function ranNum () {
  schedule();
  function schedule() {
    setTimeout(go, Math.random() * 10000);
  }
  function go() {
    var myNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
    display(myNum+' ');
    if (--counter > 0) { // For the snippet, stop after 20
      schedule();
    }
    // No return, it doesn't make any sense to return something from a timer function
  }
}
function display(msg) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", msg);
}
ranNum();
```

Comment: thanks, no worries about document.write, it's not a real-life project, I'm just using it instead of console.logging :)